# When else with partition by isn't working in redshift queries

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift, partition

I would like to exclude the categories sub_tag1, sub_tag2 and sub_tag3 of tag from the TAG_SALES_by_month but the rest whatever i mentioned in the where condition need to be included in the count. I couldn't achieve the desired result.can anyone help me to achieve the same, which would be very much appreciated.

```
select o.tag, 

 o.SOME, o.THING, o.ILIKE, o.date, c.THE, c.MOST,
date_part(month, o.date) as Month,
date_part(day, o.date) as day,
count(o.id) over (partition by day, CUST_Id) as SALE_NO,
count(o.id) over (partition by Month, CUST_Id) as SALE_NO_by_month,
count(case when (tag <> 'sub_tag1' AND tag <> 'sub_tag2' AND tag <> 'sub_tag3')  then o.id else 0 END) over (partition by Month, CUST_Id) as TAG_SALES_by_month,
c.id as CUST_Id

from order_info o
left join config c on o.SOME = c.SOME

where date >= '05/01/2021' AND tag in ('sub_tag1', 'sub_tag2', 'sub_tag3', 'sub_tag4', 'sub_tag5',
 'sub_tag6') AND ILIKE = 'JACK'

 group by o.tag, o.SOME, o.THING, o.ILIKE, o.date, c.THE, c.MOST, CUST_Id, o.id
 order by date
```

Comment: Please provide sample data, current results, and expected results.  The only thing I can see at a glance here is that your `ELSE 0` should be `ELSE NULL` (or leave the `ELSE` out entirely, since it will default to `NULL` anyway).  0 will still be counted as 1, null will not be counted.

Comment: @AaronDietz your answer given the solution already. Else 0 part was the one which preventing the query to show me the desired result. Thank you so much...

Comment: Glad to hear that was it. I posted my comment as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per the comments, the issue here is the that `COUNT` will return 1 for any value, it counts *existence vs not existence of a value/row*.

So `COUNT(CASE WHEN... ELSE 0...)` will still count 1 on the `ELSE` condition, since 0 is a value that exists.

The solution is to use `ELSE NULL` or omit the `ELSE` clause which will default to `NULL`, because `NULL` will not be counted.